# Настройка mysql + springboot в docker-compose

Tags: mysql, spring, docker, spring-boot, docker-compose

Я пишу небольшое приложение: [ссылка на github](https://github.com/michaelkotor/crud) Ветка: spring-jbdc.
Одно из моих требований - чтобы приложение запускалось только одной командой без дополнительных конфигураций.

```
docker-compose up --build (tесли произвошли изменения в Dockerfile)
```

вот мой docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    container_name: db
    ports:
    - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: exaample
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1234
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'

  crud:
    depends_on:
      - db
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
    expose:
      - "9000"
    ports:
    - "8000:9000"
    restart: always
```

А вот и **application.yml**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: crud

driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
url: jdbc:mysql://db:3306/exaample?useSSL=false&autoReconnect=true
username: root
password: 1234

server:
  port: 9000
```

При запуске контейнера я получаю ошибку невозможности подключения к базе:

```
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

У меня есть предоположения, что я как-то неправильно использую параметры типа MYSQL_ROOT_HOST.

Comment: У меня все собралось и заработало. Может у вас что-то с настройками сети (в hosts, например что-то прописано не то)?

Comment: спасибо)  уже починил ветку) там надо было links добавить